# storing the remaining char * and pre-appending it to original char * for processing

Tags: c++, c++11, udp, c++14, c++17

I am reading from a binary file.

```
char bigbuf[5000];
    while (read(fd, bigbuf, 2) != 0) {
        uint16_t packetSize = htons(*(uint16_t *)bigbuf);
        read(fd, bigbuf + 2, packetSize - 2);   
        myParser.onUDPPacket(bigbuf, packetSize);
}
```

The packets are written in binary file are of 40 bytes, but inside onUDPPacket function I receive a packet of 61 bytes then on the second call I again receive a 60 byte packet. Now I have to write the function onUDPPacket such that on the first call it processes 40 byte of data from the 61 byte received and it has to append remaining 21 bytes in the starting of the next 60 byte of packet. How do I do this append thing ?

```
void Parser::onUDPPacket(const char *buf, size_t len)
{
}
```

Comment: Here's a simple way to figure out how to do this, and it never fails to work. Just take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down using short, simple sentences in plain English, a step-by-step process of doing this. When done, [call your rubber duck for an appointment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).  After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished!

Comment: Simply save it to a class data member. Check on next round if the data member is empty or not, if it is not, prepend. Also, use std::vector instead of char*

Comment: @Waqar How do I prepend ? its a char * buf, how do I prepend it ? using + operator ? I can have a char temp[] of remaining 21 bytes but just doing temp + buf will give me the required prepended buf ? I tried it but it is giving wrong output